# Reliability and WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

So here is the scenario...   I have a sharepoint content type that calls a wcf service to update data in another database.  The problem comes what happens if the call times out?  This process happens during check out and while I may get a failure of the SP side while waiting for the call to finish, the service end may succeed.  Any ideas on a better way to architect a solution?

Comment: Are you talking about a pure SP website/web part/ website deployed under SP?? Please provide more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using a wsDualHttpBinding and having the service perform a callback once the process is done?  You could use AJAX to call the WCF service which would perform the call in the background asynchronously.  Then when the service is finished, it can callback over the dual binding and let the SP application know it's finished.